# How can I use join and where together - Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to establish a relationship between two tables. So I want to bring blogs with status = 1. How can I do that.
My categories table looks like

```
id|category_name|status|
1 |Animals      |   0     
2 |Education    |   1     
3 |Water        |   0
```

My blogs table looks like

```
id|category_id|title      | description         |
1 |   1       |New Post 1 | Post description 1  |
2 |   2       |New Post 2 | Post description 1  |
3 |   3       |New Post 3 | Post description 1  |
4 |   2       |New Post 4 | Post description 1  |
```

How do I list blogs provided that where('status', 1) from categories table?
Please help me. thanks for your help.

Comment: mean you want blog list which category status=1..?

Comment: Yes like you said. below solution was provided thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can write query with query builder in Laravel,
Please see below code

```
$whereData= [
  ['categories.status',1]
];

$getData = Blog::join("categories",'categories.id', '=', 'blogs.category_id')
->where($whereData)
->get();
```

Above code is tested and worked.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: $getData = Blog::join("categories",'categories.id', '=', 'blogs.category_id')
            ->where('categories.status',1)
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(6)->get();  This is how I can get the last 6 . This code is giving an error.

Comment: i think issue is in " orderBy('id', 'desc') "  , you should try categories.id or blogs.id instead of  'id' in orderBy

Comment: $getData = Blog::join("categories",'categories.id', '=', 'blogs.category_id')
            ->where('categories.status',1)
            ->orderBy('blogs.id', 'desc')->take(6)->get(); Thanks for trying it corrected this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = DB::table('categories')
->join('blog', 'blog.category_id', '=','categories.id')
->select('blog.*', 'categories.category_name')->where('categories.status',1)->get();
```

Above code may help you.